# What is the meaning of $x=0$ in this trigonometric expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given: $$ \tan(2x) = \tan(2x+20°) $$
The solution should be: $2x = 2x + 20° + 180°k$ 
But then $2x$ is canceled.

My question is: what is the meaning of the expression when there's no $x$ in it?

Comment: There is no value of $x$ that satisfies that equation.

Comment: You're finding values of $x$ where the expression is true. Here it means that the "truthiness" of the expression is independent of $x$. In other words, the expression is either true for all values of $x$, or false for all values of $x$

Comment: It means there's no solution since $0=20+180k$ which is impossible

Comment: this equation has no solutions

Comment: So the answer is 'no solution' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x=2x+20+180k$$ , $k$ is an integer.

$$0=20+180k$$, $k$ is an integer.

$$-20=180k$$, $k$ is integer.

Because $k=-1/9$ is not an integer, we arrived at a contradiction, thus there is no solution. This shouldn't be a surprise as tangent has a period of $180$ degrees or $\pi$ radians.